# The usage of a comma with conjunctions

Tags: conjunctions, punctuation, coordination

I am a little confused about the usage of a comma in sentences with conjunctions.

For example:

> Dairying is concerned **not only** with the production of milk **but** with the manufacture of milk products.

Can we put a comma before *but*?

Can we say "*Dairying is concerned **not only** with the production of milk, **but** is concerned  with the manufacture of milk products.*"? Or must there be an *it* after *but* in this case?

Or is the original sentence wrong at all?

Comment: You can certainly put a comma there.  Or not.  Different strokes for different folks.  This is similar to the [Oxford comma](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/what-is-the-oxford-comma) in that the rule is debatable and the issue is the same.

Comment: I wouldn't say either is wrong, but the first is how I was taught.

Comment: @Doc that's not OC's case.

Comment: @MaulikV What's not OC's case?  I'm not saying that this is an issue of the Oxford comma, I said it was "similar to the Oxford comma in that the rule is debatable and the issue [of whether to use a comma before a conjunction] is the same".  What about that is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a comma before **but** or leave it out.  It is a matter of personal taste (or the professional opinion of your editor or publisher if you have one.)

(Myself, honestly, I think commas are, well, you know, awesome, and will use them, with rare exception, anywhere they might possibly fit.)

In your second example, you have an additional **is**, which is unnecessary: it is redundant with the initial **is**, and breaks the grammatical parallelism.  Adding an **it** just exacerbates that.

Comment: +1 But I think the redundancy is *is concerned*, not just *is*.

Answer (score 3):

The comma is not required.

Also, the structure "*...not only...but also...*" has a particular structure. The question in concern and the structure is one of the most confusing things in English grammar.

Here is a wonderful tip from [DailyWritingTips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/5-tips-for-fixing-%E2%80%9Cnot-only-but-also%E2%80%9D-errors/)-

> But before we go any further, note not only that a comma following “not only” is unnecessary but also that **also (or too or as well) is essential after but.**

The structure is `(Subject) (this) (verb) and (that)` but the correct structure is `(Subject) (verb) (this) and (that)`

So, all in all...

> Dairying is concerned *not only* with the production of milk *but also* with the manufacture of milk products.

Putting comma is extraneous. Here is the example (#5) from that page:

> “They understood that the devastation was **not solely (serves as 'not only')** about the lack of water **but also** about the way the land had been used.”

*Then where use comma before 'but'?*

When  two sentences merged into one with but – comma is required - [GrammarMonster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_before_conjunctions.htm). I also notice that the conjunction *but* takes comma before it when the latter clause is in contrast of the former one.

> He is a great swimmer **, but** he prefers to play golf.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough rep to comment. :/

At the end of your post, you asked if the original sentence was correct.  It is correct except for one thing: something to imply that *with the manufacture of milk products* is in addition to something.

- Dairying is concerned not only with the production of milk but with
  the manufacture of milk products, **too**.

If someone is going to be reading this aloud, I recommend adding a comma to help separate the "thoughts" in the sentence.  Otherwise, Codeswitcher is absolutely correct: it's a matter of personal taste.